# getting started with lex

Tags: regex, unix, lex

I need to format some hexdump like this:

```
00010: 02 03 04 05
00020: 02 03 04 08
00030: 02 03 04 08

00010: 02 03 04 05
00020: 02 03 04 05
02 03 04 05
02 03 04 08
‍
```

to

```
02 03 04 05
02 03 04 08
02 03 04
02 03 04 05
02 03 04 05
02 03 04 05
02 03 04
```

- remove the address fields, if present
- remove any `08` at the end of a paragraph (followed by an empty line)
- remove any empty lines

How can this be done using **[lex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_%28software%29)**? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be done directly using lex. Lex is a tokenizer, not a parser.

In all honesty, it can be done using a regular expression and doesn't need the complexity of a scanner generator + parser generator.

Comment: Agreed, lex is probably more tool than you need for something like this.

Answer (score 1):

If you slurp in the whole file as one string, I think these regular expressions will do what you want (written for Perl, but not tested):

```
s/^\d{4}: //mg
s/ 08\n\s*\n/\n/g
s/^\s*$//mg
```